# Bars beginning at 1 instead of 0

Tags: r, plotly

I'm trying to build a bar chart chart with a logarithmic axis, but I want the bars to begin at one instead of zero. So far I have a basic bar chart,

```
df <- data.frame(Categ=c("a","b","a","a","b"),Num=c(1,2,3,4,5),Value=c(1.56,0.85,10.6,8.9,32.8))
plot_ly(data=df,x=~Num,y=~Value,type="bar",color=~Categ) %>%
layout(yaxis=list(exponentformat='power',type='log',title=ylab),legend=list(orientation='h'))
```

And I can add white bars so everything goes from 1:

```
plot_ly(data=df,x=~Num,y=~rep(1,5),type="bar",opacity=0.0,showlegend=FALSE) %>%
add_trace(y=~(Value-1),opacity=1.0,color=~Categ,showlegend=TRUE) %>%
layout(yaxis=list(exponentformat='power',type='log'),legend=list(orientation='h'),barmode='stack')
```

The issue here is if you double click the legend, to show only category b then the white bars also disappear and any values below 1 disappear.
I'm wondering if there are any better solutions to this problem, or a way to make the white bars permanent so values less than 1 are always displayed.

Comment: Barplot and log scales do not make a lot sense since there is no zero the y axis.  The relative bar heights can be distorted depending on how close to zero you would start the graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way around this, after scanning through the documentation a bunch...
https://plot.ly/r/reference/
If you use the base command, it sets the base to whatever you need.

```
plot_ly(data=df,x=~Num,y=~(Value-1),base=1,type="bar",color=~Categ,showlegend=TRUE) %>%
layout(yaxis=list(exponentformat='power',type='log'),legend=list(orientation='h'))
```